# Difference between apc_add and apc_store?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I don't see any in the PHP docs:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-add.php

Am I missing something here? When should I use each one?

And why are there two usage definitions, one returs true and one returns array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the docs say that apc_store does `Cache a variable in the data store` and apc_add does `Caches a variable in the data store, only if it's not already stored.`. Notice the last part - "only if it's not already stored. So apc_store simply overwrites existing values already stored.

The second part is a array with errors.

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. Second syntax returns array with error keys.